# Is it possible to use a FontAwesome v5 icon within FontAwesome v4.7?

Tags: css, font-awesome, webfonts, font-awesome-5

Currently using Fontawesome v4.7 but there is an icon (fa-fire) which has been updated and is included within Fontawesome 5 package. Is it possible to update the css file or the webfonts files without downloading the whole v5 package and removing/adding files?

Comment: Instead of "downloading the whole v5 package and removing/adding files", why don't you use links from a CDN ? That way you just need to change the links, and the update is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear this might create more trouble than benefit. The icons are now split over several font-files, so you can not just exchange the font-files and edit the CSS for *just that* icon etc.

But if you really want to use the new icon (and only that *one* icon), you could use the [SVG-Sprite](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-sprites) for that. Will still require to change your code (you won't be able to access it as `fa-fire`), but hey - you'd be able to use a FA5-Icon on a FA4-Site!